# How do I combine rows that have similar values?

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to combine rows with values that are close together and use their mean as a new row. It's hard to explain so I'll try to show an example:

```
  row  chr    pos methbulk htcmeth   dist
    1 chr1     10        0     100     NA
    2 chr1 100010      100       0 100000 #
    3 chr1 100020      100       0     10 # These 3 rows should be merged 
    4 chr1 100030      100       0     10 # because their "pos" is close
    5 chr1 250030      100       0 150000
    6 chr1 350030      100      23 100000
 ....
   51 chr2 200000        0     100     NA # the methbulk and htcmeth rows should be 
   52 chr2 200010      100       0     10 # averaged when these two rows are merged
   53 chr2 300020      100       0 100010 
   54 chr2 300030      100       0     10
   55 chr2 300040      100       0     10
   56 chr2 300050      100       0     10
```

Here, pos is the "position" that a line is located at, while dist is the "distance" the pos of the current row subtracted from the previous row, calculated by `ddply(data, .(chr), transform, dist=c(NA,diff(pos)))`

Ideally, every 2 or more rows that have a distance (dist) close to each other (e.g. 1000) should be collapsed into a single row and average of methbulk and htcmeth taken and reported. After this is done, the dist column is no longer needed. Instead, a new column, "end" should specify the highest "pos" value of all the merged rows.

Therefore, the above data should be something like this:

```
  row  chr    pos methbulk htcmeth   end
    1 chr1     10        0     100     10
    2 chr1 100010      100       0 100030
    5 chr1 250000      100       0 250000 #the merged rows
    6 chr1 350000      100      23 350000
 ....
   51 chr2 200000       50      50 200010 #the average values have been taken here
   53 chr2 300020      100       0 300050
```

Any ideas? Is it necessary to even use a distance measurement? I am thinking of using logical vectors, based on the distance measurement (i.e. if distance < 1000, take rows until distance > 1000)

EDIT: What about 4 or more rows? Does the answer change significantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new column which determines which "bin" to put the data in.

To start, replace the `NA` values in `dist` with something greater than your tolerance, then use `cumsum` on the logical vector as the bin number:

```
tol = 1000
x$dist[is.na(x$dist)] <- tol + 1
x$bin <- cumsum(x$dist > tol)
aggregate(. ~ bin, data=x, FUN=mean)
##   bin  row chr    pos methbulk htcmeth     dist
## 1   1  1.0   1     10        0     100   1001.0
## 2   2  3.0   1 100020      100       0  33340.0
## 3   3  5.0   1 250030      100       0 150000.0
## 4   4  6.0   1 350030      100      23 100000.0
## 5   5 51.5   2 200005       50      50    505.5
## 6   6 54.5   2 300035      100       0  25010.0
```

Then remove the unneeded columns.

Note that this is returning the mean of the `pos` column also.

Comment: Ah, this is an interesting way to do this. Could I then obtain the min and max of the pos of each "bin" to obtain start and end?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps define an aggregation vector:

```
dat$farcat <-  ave( dat$pos, dat$chr, FUN= function(x) cumsum(1, diff(x)>1000) )
```

Then aggregate within the 'farcat' values which are now separately handled for each chromosome:

```
 aggregate( pos+methbulk ~ chr+closecat, data=dat)    # default fun is mean
```

If you also wanted a start and stop for the aggregated groups, that would be easy with aggregate as well. Could be cbind()-ed to the earlier answer

```
aggregate(pos ~ chr + farcat, data=dat, FUN=function(x) { c(min=min(x), max=max(x))} )
```